# Reflexivity for the compact open topology on a topological $\mathbb{R}$-vector space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, compactness

On page 20 of [these lectures](https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Analytic.pdf), Peter Scholze and Dustin Clausen show that a broad class of topological vector spaces is reflexive, i.e. $V \cong [[V, \mathbb{R}], \mathbb{R}]$, where we endow these hom-spaces with the compact-open topology.

I was thinking that surely it was known that these classes of topological vector spaces were reflexive long before condensed mathematics. My question is, what are broad classes of topological vector spaces which are reflexive with respect to $\mathbb{R}$ under the compact open topology, and references to proofs of this fact?

I am especially interested in compactly generated spaces.

Comment: This seems to coincide with the classical notion of *stereotype spaces*. A reference is Akbarov, [*Pontryagin Duality in the Theory of Topological Vector Spaces and in Topological Algebra*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1020929201133).